# PowerShell coding in O365

Tags: powershell, script, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a question regarding sample code. I am running some scripts in O365, "Running script" as below.

What I want to do when a PSSession enters a "Broken" state, is to pause the script, and remove broken session (`Remove-PSSession <broken session ID`) and re-connecting `PSSession` (following "Re-connecting code" as below), then restart the script. I tried to write this but but I am no familiar with coding.... Can anyone help?

```
Import-Csv D:\work\users.csv | ForEach {
Grant-CsConferencingPolicy $_.UserPrincipalName -PolicyName BposSAllModalityNoFT
}

Import-Csv D:\work\users.csv | ForEach {
Grant-CsExternalAccessPolicy $_.UserPrincipalName -PolicyName FederationOnly
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. Is there more to your script than the lines you provided?